# Uniquely identify clients with java selector

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I am writing a socket server using java.nio. As I need my server to use 0 threads I am using `java.nio.channels.Selector`. My code look as follows.

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();

   iterator.remove();

   if (!key.isValid()) {
       continue;
   }

   if (key.isAcceptable()) { // Accept client connections
       this.acceptClient(key);
   } else if (key.isReadable()) { // Read from client
       this.read(key);
   } else if (key.isWritable()) {
       this.write(key);
   }
}

    private void acceptClient(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        SocketAddress clientAddress= channel.getRemoteAddress();

        //clients is a Hashmap
        clients.put(clientAddress, new Client());
        clientConnected(clientAddress.toString());
        System.out.println("Connected to: " + clientAddress);

        channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
```

As you can see I am creating a new Client object per accepted client. What I need to do is, relevant Client object to handle their own reading and writing.

My approach is to uniquely identify clients with their address and forward it to relevant Client object.
I think using client address to uniquely identify clients is not a good approach. What is the best way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think using client address to uniquely identify clients is not a good approach.

Nothing wrong with it. The semantics of TCP/IP guarantee that every accepted socket has a different remote `SocketAddress`.

But you don't need it, or the `Map` either. Just save the `Client` as the attachment of the `SelectionKey`. That way also the `Client` will disappear along with the `SelectionKey` automatically when you close the `Channel`.

By contrast, changing to an `IdentityHashMap<SelectionKey, Client>` as suggested elsewhere gives you an opportunity to leak the `SelectionKey` and therefore its `Channel` and the `Client` too.

Comment: "Save the client as the attachment of the selectionkey". What did you mean by this?

Comment: Err, `SelectionKey.attach(new Client())`? or `channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, new Client())`? and then `Client client = (Client)key.attachment()` when you need it back?

Comment: Oh woow. It will be easy for future readers, if you can add a hint to that in your answer.

Comment: I consider it obvious. All you have to do is read the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

When you register the `Channel` with the `Selector`:

```
channel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

It will return a `SelectionKey` which you can use later when you select from the `Selector`.

Use that key to populate an `IdentityHashMap<SelectionKey,Client>` so you can direct the IO to the correct `Client` instance. As EJP points out in his answer, this will leak SelectionKeys if not properly cleaned up. If you preferred not to clean those up, you could use a `WeakHashMap` as well but then you're relying in implicit behavior instead of the explicit behavior of the Selector.

EJP's suggestion to use an attachment is probably the best bet. Although I can imagine a more complicated scenario where you might want to maintain additional attachments and maybe refactoring the attachment to be an encapsulation is of high cost.

Comment: Why an `IdentityHashMap`?

Comment: From what I gather from the docs, the keys's hashCode method is not well defined and the defined states seem to possibly overlap with other keys so I wouldn't rely on the hashcodes being unique per SelectionKey (even though the src indicates a default implementation of hashCode() which relies on the address)

Comment: It is well-defined in he Javadoc that both `equals()` and `hashCode()` are inherited from `Object`. I don't understand 'defined states seem to possibly overlap with other keys'.

Comment: It's well defined that they (currently) inherit from Object, and Object has strict requirements about what equals and hashcode must comply with. However, the implementation details on Object are left vague. Typically hashcode and equals would change based on internal state of an object; SelectionKey specifies the internal state includes what is ready, which changes over time on the SelectionKey. Because the SelectionKey class does not explicitly state that the hashcode and equals result won't change over time, I don't think it's safe to rely on a vague implementation of Object.

Comment: What is well defined is that the selector will return a reference to the same SelectionKey instance, so going with an IdenityHashMap fits in well with the explicitly defined behavior (ignoring the implicitly defined behavior)

Comment: It accomplshes exactly nothing that `Object.hashCode()` doesn't already guarantee. That is the *definition* of `System.identityHashCode()`.

Comment: You're correct, the end solution does the same thing.

The goal of the IdentityMap solution is to be explicit about the behavior instead of relying on defaults. It's a solution built upon guarantees explicitly stated in the docs instead of 'it just happens to work out'. I don't think it's safe to rely on a default identity hashcode for an object which has mutating internal state. If that's the intended behavior, it should be documented, and then we would be good. The risk is that the runtime changes behavior or the selectionkey hashcode is eventually implemented such that it is not identity.